# LUIS: recognizing more than one of the same composite entity in one utterance

Tags: json, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm new to LUIS and I'm still trying to figure things out, one thing I can't seem to figure out is how to make my LUIS app recognize what entities belong to the same composite entity when there are more than one instances in one utterance. I know this was confusing let me try to explain better:

My test app is about ordering stuff.

I have this utterance:

> purchase for me 2 red hot chilli pepper albuns and an amazing spiderman figure please

And the JSON returned is this:

```
{
  "query": "purchase for me 2 red hot chilli pepper albuns and an amazing spiderman figure please",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "Order",
    "score": 0.9981847
  },
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "Order",
      "score": 0.9981847
    },
    {
      "intent": "Read",
      "score": 0.0023417694
    },
    {
      "intent": "None",
      "score": 0.00118408469
    }
  ],
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "red hot chilli pepper albuns",
      "type": "Item.Description",
      "startIndex": 18,
      "endIndex": 45,
      "score": 0.8821352
    },
    {
      "entity": "amazing spiderman figure",
      "type": "Item.Description",
      "startIndex": 54,
      "endIndex": 77,
      "score": 0.9167113
    },
    {
      "entity": "2",
      "type": "Item.Quantity",
      "startIndex": 16,
      "endIndex": 16,
      "score": 0.9843564
    },
    {
      "entity": "an",
      "type": "Item.Quantity",
      "startIndex": 51,
      "endIndex": 52,
      "score": 0.948889554
    }
  ]
}
```

It recognizes the entities correctly but it doesnt know that the "2" corresponds to the "red hot chilli pepper albuns" and the "an" corresponds to "the amazing spiderman figure"

My entities are:

```
Item.Quantity - simple entity
Item.Description - simple entity 
Item.Number - simple entity
Item - composite entity with the above as children
```

Is this even possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its totally possible. And you are on the right track of using Composite entities, just the training of the composite entities needs to be changed. Firstly for the composite entities, the child entities should be added and trained (which you have done).

Next is to mark the composite entities. Go to the Order intent and for any utterance lets say :

> purchase for me 2 red hot chilli pepper albuns

select the **`Item.Quantity`** entity and then select ***Wrap in composite entity*** from the list. A green line, under the words will appear, now **move your cursor to the right** till red hot chilli pepper albuns (or till any entity you want to wrap) and you will notice that the green line follows indicating a composite entity. Select the composite name **`Item`** from the list that appears.

For multiple composite entities in the same utterance, like

> purchase for me 2 red hot chilli pepper albuns and an amazing spiderman figure please

repeat the same procedure, except that the first composite entity would be wrapped and trained for `2 red hot chilli pepper albuns` and the next composite entity would be wrapped and trained for `an amazing spiderman figure`

Don't forget to Train and publish the LUIS app.

For more in depth understanding of composite entities take a look at [Luis tutorial - composite entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-composite-entity)

Comment: Now that you explained it looks so obvious I shouldve figured it out by myself. Thank you that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: I can move my cursor wherever I want unter some entities after selecting a composite for the leftmost entity. The green line will only appear under the first entity. And yes, the second entity is also part of the same composite entity definition. 
Did they change something over the 1.5 years since your comment?